# Recursion for testing if arrays elements are equal from certain indexes

Tags: java, recursion

I am learning recursion and I just can't get why this method isn't working properly.

```
public static boolean theSame(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
        if(arr[start]==arr[end]) {
            if(start!=end) {
                start++;
                theSame(arr, start, end);
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

}
```

the array is `4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4` and i am testing it from indices 1 and 5. What gives? Why is it not working? I'm assuming it has to do with my `if(start!=end)` condition but I am unsure.

I forgot to add, that the method returns false when it should clearly return true.

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: It is returning false.

Comment: try `return theSame(arr, start, end);` otherwise you are ignoring all the results except the first one you match.
`

Comment: @AeriaGlorisia remember to run a debug when code is not acting as intented, that way you can check the values as they are tested and locate errors that are often hard to see by a glanse

Comment: @AeriaGlorisia If it doesn't return anything, the method won't get interrupted, and you will eventually reach the line `return false;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static boolean theSame(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
    if(arr[start]==arr[end]) {
        if(start!=end) {
            start++;
            theSame(arr, start, end);  // here's your problem
            // return theSame(arr, start, end); might work better
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can do it in one line though.

```
public static boolean theSame( int[] arr, int start, int end ) {
    return start >= end || (
        arr[ start ] == arr[ end ] && theSame( arr, start + 1, end )
    );
}
```

Comment: I want to see if I have the logic behind this correct. If  the first segment is true(`start>=end`) then it will proceed to the second segment, and if the second segment is true it will call the function again correct?

Comment: If the first segment is true, it will *not* proceed.  The logical "OR" operator `||` has short-circuit semantics; if `x` is `true`, `x || y` evaluates to `true` *without evaluating `y`*. If the first segment is false, that is, `start < end`, then we check if the current element is identical to the last element and also the results for all subsequent array entries (by making a recursive call).  Recursion looks a lot like mathematical induction.  You have a base case (here, if the section of the array to consider is empty) and an inductive step: knowing the `n` case, what's the `n + 1` case?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace

`theSame(arr, start, end);`

with

`return theSame(arr, start, end);`

In the existing implementation, value returned by `inner` method call is ignored and it ends up returning `false` (last line). Following should work fine:

```
public static boolean theSame(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
    if (arr[start] == arr[end]) {
        if (start != end) {
            start++;
            return theSame(arr, start, end);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```